# Is it possible for Dropzone to wait for a promise to resolve before processing a file?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, dropzone.js

I am using the latest version of [Dropzone](https://www.dropzone.dev/) (currently v6) and I unable to find a way to make Dropzone wait for a promise to resolve before it starts processing a dropped file.

On the Dropzone's init function I have the following:

```
init: function () {
    this.on("addedfile", someAsyncMethod);
    this.on("processing", file => {
        console.log("It always enters here before 'someAsyncMethod' promise resolves!");
    });
}
```

Here is the `someAsyncMethod` code:

```
const someAsyncMethod = async () => {
    const url = "https://my-service/api/some-method";
    const result = await fetch(url);
    // do some stuff here with the result
}
```

No matter what, the event handler for processing alway starts before the on addedfile mehod handler resolves... Is it possible to make Dropzone wait for the onadded handler promise to resolve before it moves on to process the fil added to the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider setting the `autoProcessQueue` option to `false`. As per [the documentation](https://docs.dropzone.dev/configuration/basics/upload-queue):

> If you have the option `autoProcessQueue` set to `true` then the queue is immediately processed, after a file is dropped or an upload finished, by `calling.processQueue()` which checks how many files are currently uploading, and if it’s less than `options.parallelUploads`, `.processFile(file)` is called.
>
> If you set `autoProcessQueue` to `false`, then `.processQueue()` is never called implicitly. This means that you have to call it yourself when you want to upload all files currently queued.

This should allow you to invoke processing after `someAsyncMethod` completes.

Comment: yup, that is the trick, it worked! Thank you!